# Fallo por escritura rápida

Tags: c#

En la aplicación en c# que estoy programando tengo campos de autocompletar, por ejemplo, uno es el de país, es decir, la gente según va escribiendo el nombre del país carga una lista con los países que coinciden con lo que se escribe. Lo hago así:

```
private void PaisEncuentro_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd;
            SqlDataReader lector;
            string sql;
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);
            AutoCompleteStringCollection coleccion = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            sql = "SELECT Nombre FROM tbl_Pais";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
            conexion.Open();
            lector = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (lector.Read())
                coleccion.Add(lector.GetString(0));
            conexion.Close();
            PaisEncuentro.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coleccion;
            PaisEncuentro.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            PaisEncuentro.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        }
```

El problema que tengo es que, muchas veces, si escribo el nombre del país muy rápido me falla la aplicación y no se a que es debido. No se si será debido a que escribo el contenido sql directamente en el código (no se hacerlo de otro modo), es decir, que no hago una función que llamo cada vez que se hace el keypress o, en definitiva, estoy perdido. Me falla pocas veces, pero me falla o bien en este campo de país o en otros que uso también.

Gracias

Comment: Qué significa "Me falla"? El programa se cierra sin aviso? El programa se traba? El programa da error? El programa deja de responder? El programa filtra memoria? El programa cobra vida propia? Si no nos dices cuál es el mensaje de error, cómo sabremos que "falla"?

Comment: El programa da un error, en cuanto me vuelva a pasar te lo plasmo aquí para que lo veas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoCompleteStringCollection se encarga de filtrar el autocompletado por ti. Cuando haces:

- textBox2.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

Le dices al textbox que el autocompleta será a partir de un lista del tipo AutoCompleteStringCollection

y cuando haces

- textBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coleccion;

**Ligas** la lista con el textbox. Esto es lo mismo que te hemos intentado explicar en muchas de tus preguntas.

Cuando una lista y un datasource están ligados, los cambios son automaticos. Entonces **sobra** sobreescribir el datasource cada vez. Y en este caso del autocompletar, la misma clase `AutoCompleteStringCollection` se encarga del filtrado, por lo que **NO** debes colocarlo en el TextChanged

Paso 1)
Creas una función de inicializado con tu mismo código

```
private void PaisEncuentroAutoCompleteInit()
{
            SqlCommand cmd;
            SqlDataReader lector;
            string sql;
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);
            AutoCompleteStringCollection coleccion = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            sql = "SELECT Nombre FROM tbl_Pais";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
            conexion.Open();
            lector = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (lector.Read())
                coleccion.Add(lector.GetString(0));
            conexion.Close();
            PaisEncuentro.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coleccion;
            PaisEncuentro.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            PaisEncuentro.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
}
```

Paso 2) la  llamas en el constructor

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   PaisEncuentroAutoCompleteInit();
}
```

Y listo, porque solo es necesario setear **UNA** sola vez el autocompleta **NO todas las veces** que cambia el texto

Comment: Gracias, la verdad es que me has ayudado mucho con tu respuesta

Comment: Me alegro te haya servido, suerte en tu proyecto!!!